# react-native start unexpected token

Tags: javascript, babeljs, react-native

I'm getting an error on the start command when using react-native. The file 
*projectName*/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/file.js 
on line 63 is giving the error

```
constructor(options, {
                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/cread/WHOOP-ReactNative/whoopApp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cread/WHOOP-ReactNative/whoopApp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js:123:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": *name*,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.2",
    "react-native": "0.54.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-sound": "0.10.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.0.0-alpha.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I've tried deleting my node_modules file, clearing the npm cache, and reinstalling but to no avail. The problem seems to be in the cli.js file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was using the last version of the react-native and nodejs. Unfortunately, I needed to go back to the version 8.11.2. In my case, it is resolved.
I removed the node_modules dir.

```
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ nvm install 8.11.2
$ nvm use 8.11.2
$ npm install react-native@0.54.1
```

Comment: This didn't seem like an obvious thing to do for me, but what I discovered is that my default version was very old (run 'nvm ls') which is used by Xcode.  Although my terminal had the newest version of node, I couldn't tell Xcode was using the old version which causes the bug above.